# jQuery animated flipOutX

Tags: jquery

I have this demo of what I want to do in jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/2xppM/
```

I tried to do this on my host but it doesn't work.
This is what I wrote in my file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>      

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.mesaj-necitit').on('click', '#delete', function(event){
    var $row = $(this).closest('.mesaj-necitit');
    $row.addClass('animated flipOutX');
});
});//]]>  

</script></head>
    <body>
         <div class='mesaj-necitit'><a href="#">

            <div >
            dasdas</div>

            <div>sadsa</div>
            <div>sdas</div>      
            </a><div >
            sda
                <a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a>         ;  
            </div></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find a problem with my code. 
I would really need some help.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for? the fiddle is working fine. refer http://jsfiddle.net/F5y8a/embedded/result,js,css,html/ for more for FlipOutX

Comment: Have you included your "gumby.css" and "animate.css" in html file ?